# Is the use of "for" where "because of" would fit allowed?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Take the following example:

> You probably couldn't see for the lights but you were staring straight at me.

I get that the `for` there could've been replaced by `because of` to the same effect, right?

Comment: There is a significant difference in the tone of the two versions.  "Because" is far more clinical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. However this usage of for is more prevalent in British English than in American English.

See the following response from [here](http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/7163-for-vs-because-of/).

> "For" is a causal word, primarily functioning as a preposition. Because "for" is roughly equivalent to the other major causal words -- the subordinating conjunctions because, since, and as -- some grammarians have also classified "for" as a subordinating conjunction. Others -- such as Garner's Modern American Usage (Oxford Univeristy Press, 2009) -- disagree.
> As a native American English speaker, I view for/because as being similar in meaning, but different -- and not fully interchangeable. For instance, for does not feel right in your sentence, while because of does.
> Swan's Pratical English Usage (Oxford University Press UK, 2005) tells us because puts more emphasis on the reason, and most often introduces new information which is not known to the reader. For introduces new information but suggests that the reason is given as an afterthought. For clauses, used in this sense, are more common in formal, written British English than in American English.
> I'm leaving because I'm fed up. I decided to have lunch, for I was hungry.
> As an American, the for sentence sounds stilted, and I would suggest because is the better choice. I would not consider using for in the first sentence.

My claim that the use of "for" in place of "because of" is more prevalent in British English than in American English was founded on this research carried out by BYU into the matter:

> "You can see the registers that use of "for" is normally found in in
> contemporary British English (per million words):
>
> SPOKEN 0.0
>
> FICTION 0.4
>
> NEWSPAPER 0.7
>
> ACADEMIC 0.6
>
> MISC 0.5
>
> And in American English registers:
>
> SPOKEN 0.1
>
> FICTION 0.4
>
> MAGAZINE 0.2
>
> NEWSPAPER 0.1
>
> ACADEMIC 0.3
>
> As far as Time magazine is concerned, that use seems to have had it's
> ups and downs of popularity over the decades:
>
> 1920s 0.5
>
> 1930s 0.5
>
> 1940s 0.3
>
> 1950s 0.5
>
> 1960s 0.2
>
> 1970s 0.2
>
> 1980s 0.0
>
> 1990s 0.1
>
> 2000s 0.5

Comment: I associate this also with colloquial American English, in the American South and elsewhere, and in at least two idioms common in the US :  "can't win for losing" and "can't see the forest for the trees."

Comment: @vstrong Soon enough, it will be "can't see the forest because trees"

I do find this use of `because` casually delightful, though.

Comment: As one US native speaker, I see nothing "colloquial" or regional about this use of *for*. I've lived on both coasts and also in the midwest. I also wonder about the claim that this is more prevalent in British English - reference?

Comment: @Drew The phrase I got as an example is the name of a song by a British band. Not that this is a reference for something, but, you know... yeh.

Comment: In response to those questioning about the prevalence of the use of "for" in place of "because of" in British vs American English, please see the details that I have included in my answer, from BYU, on the matter.

Comment: Sadly, OP was really asking about the 'because of' vs 'for' synonymity. vstrong's comment picks up on this.